# The output of the tree to a string

Tags: codeigniter, recursion, tree

My table `[cat_id,title,pid]`. I need to get all the child sub-categories ID`s in the following format:

```
[1] =>Array ( [cat_id] => 2 [title] => TEST [pid] => 1 ),

[2] =>Array ( [cat_id] => 3 [title] => TEST [pid] => 1 ),

[3] =>Array ( [cat_id] => 4 [title] => TEST [pid] => 2 ), 

[4] =>Array ( [cat_id] => 5 [title] => TEST [pid] => 3 )
```

Purpose - using ID`s of the childs, to get all of these items.

I tried to do something as the following code, but it does not work:

```
public function get_ids($tree,$cid = 0)
{

    $data = $this->db->select('cat_id, title, pid')
                     ->where('pid',$cid)
                     ->get('catalog');

    $result = array_push($tree,$data->result_array());

    if($data->num_rows() > 0){

        foreach ($data->result_array() as $r) {

            return $this->get_ids($result,$r['cat_id']);

        }   
    }
    else{
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Maybe there is better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code to get all child ids by given parent id.

```
function fnGetChildCatelogs($id) {

    $qry = "SELECT cat_id FROM catalog WHERE pid = $id";

    $rs = mysql_query($qry);    

    $arrResult = array();    

    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {

        # It has children, let's get them.

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

            # Add the child to the list of children, and get its subchildren

            $arrResult[$row['cat_id']] = fnGetChildCatelogs($row['cat_id']);

        }

    }

    return $arrResult;

}
```

Comment: This might give you the conceptual idea, but please don't use this code. Codeigniter gives you a much better (safer!) way of querying the database.

Comment: this is a common code for recursive. Can add code igniter function before u down voting.

Comment: Thanks. I had already modified this function. It may be useful for someone: 
public function get_ids($cid)
{
    
    $qry = $this->db->select('catalog_id')
                    ->from('catalog')
                    ->where('parentid',$cid)
                    ->get();

    $arrResult = array();

    if($qry->num_rows > 0) {
        
        $t = $qry->result_array();
        
        foreach($t as $row){
            $arrResult[$row['catalog_id']] = $this->get_ids($row['catalog_id']);
        }

    }

    return $arrResult;
}